# JDBC DB2 Driver Timer Threads stuck in BLOCKED state

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, thread-dump

I have a Java application hanging indefinitely, intermittently till the server is restarted

Looking at thread dumps, I have no clue why one of the TimerThread is spin up by underlying **JDBC DB2** driver and goes into **BLOCKED** state and Tomcat Thread goes into **WAITING** state

The Timer thread "*Timer-140423*" is waiting to lock an object which is held by Tomcat Thread "*tomcat-http--38*"

Not sure why this would happen and how to mitigate this. Appreciate any direction to troubleshoot this behavior!

I've been trying to simulate this behavior in lower environments by various load testing methods (no luck so far). The performance analyzer I use behaves similar with my load tests in lower environments v/s at the time when the issue occurs in production

**Thread Dump:** (elided)

```
"Timer-140423" #140723 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2b9c208000 nid=0x19012 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f267ffba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.l(a.java:1361)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000086226278> (a com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:641)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:306)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:337)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.a(wb.java:400)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.<init>(wb.java:78)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:323)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:704)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.a(o.java:246)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.en.c(en.java:946)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mo.run(mo.java:27)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"tomcat-http--38" #68 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2c6ceb8800 nid=0x11715 in Object.wait() [0x00007f281ffd1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.j(o.java:266)
    - locked <0x0000000086226690> (a com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fn.ec(fn.java:741)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fn.executeUpdate(fn.java:717)
    - locked <0x0000000086226278> (a com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:877)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.my.app.FixTheFoxDAOJdbcImpl.completedChapter(FixTheFoxDAOJdbcImpl.java:1787)
```

---

**Config/Env details:**

```
Java             : jdk1.8.0_144
Tomcat           : tomcat-8.5.13.B.RELEASE
App Server       : Pivotal tcServer 3.2.5
Spring Version   : 4.5.3
DB Conn Pooling  : commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
Database         : DB2 Version: 11.1.0
JDBC/DB2 Driver  : db2jcc4-1.0.0.jar
```

---

On a side note, I can certainly try using tomcat-dbcp or configure data source via JNDI to see if that helps, but not sure how to test or if issue would really be fixed and not appear again in future (until any configuration changes)